# Using "ls" to print full path without using trailing "*"

Tags: shell, unix, tcsh

To print full path to a file, I know we can use

`ls /a/b/c/*`

However, I am generating a huge list of files

`ls ../../../x/*/y/*/z/*/`

When I do

`ls ../../../x/*/y/*/z/*/`

It is very fast and takes a second to get over 100,000 files

However, this does not give me the full or relative path. So I need to do

`ls ../../../x/*/y/*/z/*/*`

This is very very slow, takes a few minutes.

Is there a way to use the above command without trailing `*` and get the full or relative path? I am okay with both.

Comment: Did you try `ls -R ../../../x/` or `find ../../../x/ -ls`?

Comment: `me the full or relative path` use `readlink` for that. What exactly do you want?

Comment: ls -R, find ... both are extremely slow, remember, I am trying to list multiple directories doing 100s of thousands of files. So ls ../*/A/*/B/*/c/*.... this is very slow if I use find or ls -R or use a trailing *.

Comment: Note (1) that in general, using `ls` programatically is bad practice (AFAIK, all the reasoning in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs applies to the csh family as well -- though I'm no expert on non-POSIX shells, so use a grain of salt); and (2) that you can tell `ls` not to sort its results, which improves performance rather dramatically.

Comment: `find` is the way to go here, not `ls`.

Comment: @tadman yes, find works, however ls was much much faster than find. That is why I was exploring using ls. Without "*" at the end it does not print the entire path of the file, and with * its agonizingly slow for very large number of files.. Find takes minutes, while ls took seconds for same number of files.

Comment: @accdias -R again is very slow does not even complete for few hundred thousand files in more than 5 minutes.

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a huge difference in speed here, but it could be relating to how `find` and `ls` recurse and handle wildcards. You may want to test with and without the trailing `/` on both `find` and `ls` several times in a row, to see what's going on.

Comment: Due to file caching, any method is likely to be very slow the first time, and very fast the second. Also note that glob expansion is up to the shell, not `ls` or `find`. `find ../../../x/*/y/*/z/*/ | wc -l` should be at least as fast as `ls ../../../x/*/y/*/z/*/ | wc -l` when running both twice and discarding the first result.